# How to Remove shortcut arrow from desktop icons?

Tags: gnome, icons

How do I turn off the arrow for desktop icons?

Comment: are you on gnome or kde? and btw what icons are you seeing an arrow on? Gnome doesn't normally put an arrow unless it's a symlink.

Comment: i'm on gnome and it's a symlink to a portable program in a folder from http://portablelinuxapps.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is kind of hackish, but you could rename all the `emblem-symbolic-link.png` and
`emblem-symbolic-link.svg` icons to something else like `emblem-symbolic-link.png.bak` and  `emblem-symbolic-link.svg.bak` respectively. Use `locate emblem-symbolic-link` to find where they are.

But is there any reason you need to use a symlink?
Otherwise you could use a Launcher. Right-click on your desktop and select
`Create Launcher...`, and click on the `Browse...` button and select your portable program.
Write a name for your Launcher and (optionally) select a different icon and your done.

[image]

Comment: Launchers are not navigable when in a modal window, like when you are saving a file (they just appear as the .desktop file they actually are). I found it very useful to include symlinks and *NOT* launchers in the Desktop to the folder you are currently working on, so you can open/save files through modal windows just clicking on "dektop", and then the desired folder.