# How to resize/hide arrows on the Desktop icons?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, .desktop

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04LTS.  So far, everything is running well except my desktop icons sometimes exhibit a massive arrow (this is the case of the `*.desktop` files:

[image: arrow]

Is there a way to resize and or hide these arrows?  I did not see any possibility in `gnome-tweaks`.
To make it clear: in the above icons, `Corbeille` (created by the system) is what I would like to see.  `Veramtex` and `Pycharm` both are `.desktop` files with the corresponding icons.  Only there appears a large arrow on both.  Could I get rid of those?
Here is the content of `Pycharm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Pycharm
Icon=/..../pycharm-community-2020.2/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=/..../pycharm-community-2020.2/bin/pycharm.sh
Name[fr_BE]=Pycharm
```

And this is icon `pycharm.png` (without the arrow)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- While [the referenced post](https://askubuntu.com/q/14453/26246) by Ali I. Demirel suggests removing/renaming icons or creating `.desktop` files. I expect them to work.
- Here is an alternative option, resizing the icons or make them fully transparent (extreme ratio 1%/10000%~5%/2000%).

  ```
  sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16
  sudo find /usr/share/icons/Yaru/ -name "emblem-symbolic-link.png" \
  -exec cp -v {} {}.bak \; \
  -exec convert {} -resize 50% \
  -background transparent -gravity SouthEast -extent 200% {} \;
  ```

  1. `sudo`:`/usr/share/icons/Yaru/` is a system directory
  2. `find ... -name "emblem-symbolic-link.png"`: Search for icons
  3. `find ... -exec cp {} {}.bak \;`: Make a backup copy
  4. `find ... -exec convert {} -resize 50% -background transparent -gravity SouthEast -extent 200% {} \;`

     Resize it down to 50% (half), Set default background color, Set default position, Extant image back to original size which is 200% (double).

  Logout/Login again to apply (Or Alt+F2-r to restart Gnome-Shell if you are Not using Wayland)
- To restore them back to original:

  ```
  sudo find /usr/share/icons/Yaru/ -name "emblem-symbolic-link.png.bak" -exec sh -c 'cp -v {} $(dirname {})/$(basename -s.bak {})' \;
  ## worst case, reinstall icons
  sudo apt --reinstall install yaru-theme-icon
  ```

  Logout/Login again to apply (Or Alt+F2-r to restart Gnome-Shell if you are Not using Wayland)
- Results for 50%/200% ratio in below screenshot:

  [image: Image: Results for 50%/200% ratio in below screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough points for a comment, but I believe what you are looking was solved here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=272279 if those arrows that you do not like are *symbolic links*.

If they are symbolic links and the arrows are just impossible to remove, you could try to create your own "launcher"s with the correct icons.

Creating your own launcher strategy form the link:

> A poster on FB’s Linux Mint for Beginners showed me how to make a desktop launcher for a folder
>
> Open terminal, enter command
>
> `$ xed ~/Desktop/link.desktop`
>
> Then paste this data, (7 lines), into `xed` :-
>
> ```
>    [Desktop Entry] 
>    Type=Application 
>    Name=(name you want to use for the folder’s link) 
>    Comment=(however you want to describe the link)
>    Icon=(path to icon to use) 
>    Exec=(path to folder) 
>    Terminal=false
> ```
>
> Save file and return to terminal, enter command :-
>
> `$ chmod +x ~/Desktop/link.desktop`
>
> And there on the desktop will be a link to the folder without the `!@$%&*` little linky arrow!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Well, that link actually gives multiple solution. Resize arrow, Remove arrow (transparent) or Creating ".desktop" Launcher . Just copy those solutions from the link and you answer will be perfect to me.

Comment: There was also this (https://askubuntu.com/a/14463/852902) answer from 10 years that suggests manipulating the icons.

Comment: Thank you for your help and hints.  I edited the question with a little bit more details.

Comment: @AliI.Demirel , I think removing the icon or replacing it with transparent one is the best and quickest way that fix it for all programs. Instead of making Desktop for each tool you install in the future.

Comment: @AliI.Demirell : your approach of creating a desktop file is what I had done in 18.04, correctly showing the specified icon.  Since 20.04, there is this large arrow on top op the icon, almost covering it completely. So, it does not help.

Comment: @user.dz : could you be more specific?  I had a look at replacing the 'emblem-symbolic-link.png' approach from the icon theme (Yaru in my case) but this is not easy: I experienced crashes in my session trying to rename all those icons.  Besides, I consider that as overkill for 3 too large arrows.